# Android intent opposite of setComponent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I know I can force an intent to use a specific `application/activity` by using `intent.setComponent()`. But is there a way to say that it should not use a specific `app/activity`?

Why I need this:
My application will be able to respond to several `urls (like http://www.companyname.com/something/12345)`. If my app launches cause of an Intent to this url, I'll check if I have the needed data to handle this. (In my example, something with id 12345). If I'm not able to do something useful with the intent, I create a new Intent with the same data, so the user can try to view the content in its browser.

This is the moment my problem occurs. When I start my newly created intent, my app appears again in the list of apps that can handle this. But I already know that my app can't do anything with this intent. The user already knows that my app can't handle the intent, but still it'd be nice if my app just didn't appear in this list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that works is when creating the new intent, instead of `intent.setData(uri)` I do `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html")`.
This causes that my app disappears from the list. At the moment it's a solution that works :) But still I'd like to know if there are better ways to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Intent-Filters for your app and set up the [URI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) with *wildcards* as you need, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs) for more information. With some additional info via an action or category, you may ensure, that your app it the only one (not) matching against the intent.